# "Java Heap space" error in Ireport 4.8.0

Tags: java, ireport

[image]on the iReport 4.8.0,

i create a new dataset and choose 3 tables for the dataset to include,

when i push "next" i get the error : "Java Heap space"

searched this forum and tried the solution suggested and nothing helped.

i tried changing the ireport.conf file values from :   -J-Xmx512m    to -J-Xmx1024m or even -J-Xmx2048m.    it doesn't change anything.

also checked "use visualizer" but i don't know what it is and how to work with it.  anyway, checking the "use visualizer" didn't solve the problem.

any more ideas ?

Comment: can you post your conf file? The -J part of the parameter is confusing me, then again I am no iReport expert.

Comment: # ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/4.8.0"
default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/4.8.0"

# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
default_options="--branding ireport -J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
# for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch

Comment: if i change the xmx to 1024, the iReport doesn't launch at all.

Comment: my guess is these paremters are not being passed to the actual vm, I dont know enough bout iReport to help you. How much memory does the process have? What does visualvm tell you?

Comment: i copied the query into MySQL and noticed it returns 2 million rows!. so i narrow it down using where clause and tried again. it worked. i guess my query was just too big for the IReport to handle. i didn't solve the actual problem but override it for now, thank you.